# QEMU VM has no IP

Tags: network-interface, qemu

I tried to run a VM on QEMU, but the VM is up without an IP address associated with `eth0`. I configured the bridge and tap interface on the host, and I can see that:

```
brctl show bro
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
bro             8000.bedc8d16e7d8       no              eno1
                                                        tap0
```

The interfaces look good:

```
ip addr show bro
3: bro: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:dc:8d:16:e7:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.112/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic bro
       valid_lft 540129sec preferred_lft 540129sec
    inet6 fe80::bcdc:8dff:fe16:e7d8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip addr show eno1
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bro state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 98:90:96:9d:d9:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ip addr show tap0
8: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bro state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:74:5b:04:81:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the command I use to run the VM:

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -nographic -pflash flash0.img -pflash flash1.img -drive if=none,file=CentOS-7-aarch64-Minimal-1810.iso,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -netdev type=tap,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=bc:dc:8d:16:e7:d8, -hda centos7-arm.img
```

At the guest there is no IP, even though DHCP is no:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip link show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:dc:8d:16:e7:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

After I tried to config from CentOS `nmtui`, `service network restart` failed. Found in log:

```
localhost.localdomain network[4058]: Bringing up interface eth0: Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
```

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I ran `kvm` guests directly from the command line (I prefer `libvirt`, or more recently Proxmox).

However, looking at the interface definitions at the host, and comparing it to my working configuration, the most obvious difference is that your `tap0` interface has IP address 192.168.100.222/24 whereas mine has no IP address. (The guest defines an IP address, obtained from DHCP. The host interface should not have one.)

```
# brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.009c029758d6       no              eth0
                                                        vnet5

# ip addr show vnet5
12: vnet5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:3c:75:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe3c:7533/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


# ssh vmguest ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3c:75:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.15/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe3c:7533/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Did you set that IP address on `tap0` yourself, or was it a side-effect of your `kvm` command?